# Convert project from Android Studio version 2 to 3- problem with configuration

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I have problem with configuration of android project. I upgraded Android Studio [AS] from v2 to v3 and got many problems. I changed gradle as is in documentation:
gradle-wrapper, gradle plugin version, repositories google or jcenter instead of maven. Please look at configuration:
I have project called mytwayapp which have build.gradle:

```
  buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0'
        //{ url "http://jcenter.bintray.com/" }
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

    allprojects {
        repositories {
            google()
            jcenter()
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        implementation project(':app')
    }
```

Next I  have module called app with build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
//    buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mytway.activity.registerformactivity"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    dexOptions {
        preDexLibraries = false;
        javaMaxHeapSize "2g"
    }
    sourceSets { main { assets.srcDirs = ['src/main/assets', 'src/main/res/assets/fonts'] } }

    testOptions {
        unitTests.returnDefaultValues = true
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }


}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v13:23.1.1'
    implementation 'joda-time:joda-time:2.9.4'
    implementation files('../libs/MPAndroidChart-v3.0.1.jar')

    //to remove when Dex is over memory
    testImplementation group: 'org.powermock', name: 'powermock-api-easymock', version: '1.6.6'
    testImplementation 'org.powermock:powermock-mockito-release-full:1.5.4'
    testImplementation 'org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito:1.6.6'
    testImplementation 'org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:1.5.1'
    testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-all:1.9.5'
    testImplementation 'org.powermock:powermock-mockito-release-full:1.6.1'
    testImplementation 'org.easymock:easymock:3.1'
//    testCompile files('build/lib/powermock-easymock-1.6.6-full.jar') 
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Next is gradle-wrapper:

```
#Thu Mar 16 20:14:22 CET 2017
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.6-all.zip
```

Problem: 
I cannot sync with gradle,If I try then error: 
Could not initialize class com.android.tools.idea.gradle.eclipse.GradleImport

When I try install from cmd, then:

```
./gradlew install -x test

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\android\BitBucket\mytwayapp\build.gradle' line: 22

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'mytwayapp'.
> Could not find method implementation() for arguments [project ':app'] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s
```

It means that problem is with main build.gradle with dependencies to ":app" but it looks good. 
I tried refreshed, rebuild, invalidate, restarted and still have a problem.
Project structure looks strange here is a screen:
[image]

[image]

ANSWER: 
Tips from below are not worked, I downgrade Android Studio from 3.4 to 3.1 and after some cosmetics change it compile. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Try to update to latest versions:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:x.x.x'
}
```

And `buildToolsVersion` in `build.gradle`

Answer (score 0):

Try change de compileSDkVersion and targetSdkVersion with the same number prefix of buildToolsVersion in app gradle file, like this:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
    //    buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mytway.activity.registerformactivity"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
}
```